# Kentico 10 Preview Links and Bundled CSS

Tags: kentico

We would like to use the Show Preview link via the General tab to share a link to an unpublished page for review. Unfortunately, the page generated seems unable to resolve the bundled .css and javascript and generates 404s for those files.

Anyone know of a way for the preview pages to resolve the bundled css properly?

Comment: Can you provide the URL that is being generated for the bundled .css and .js that's throwing the 404?  There may be some clues in that!

Comment: I can't share it but I can confirm the preview links work when the EnableOptimizations is false but not when true. The preview page can't find the bundled css.

Answer (score 0):

If your links are not resolving then you have incorrect or invalid syntax in your CSS.

Regarding turning off minimization and it working further confirms your syntax is not correct. The minimization engine fails when it finds incorrect syntax.

To check this turn on minimization and load a page. Download the CSS from the source and look at the last line. There will be an error in the CSS if it has failed to minimize.

Comment: The links work fine when minimization is turned off but only fail when minimization and bundling is on and only with the preview functionality.  It is the preview functionality that can't resolve the links when they are bundled. The links are correct for site minimization and bundling generally.